# SVG clipping path scaling

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, clipping

I am currently trying to get an image with an SVG clipping path to scale with the browser (image needs to be 100% of browser width). I have read in several places that applying both `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and `transform="scale(0.01)"` is the solution, however I am unable to get this to work. Whenever I apply those, the image disappears.

No doubt something simple I'm missing?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/YepbqP)

**HTML**

```
<img id="preview-img" width="100%" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg" style="clip-path: url(&quot;#clipPolygon&quot;);" class="moving">
<svg width="0" height="0" >
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.01)">
    <polygon id="poly1" points="317 343,966 254,964 -6,610 -5">
      <animate id="poly1Anim" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="" fill="freeze" />
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

If you remove the two attributes mentioned above, the image shows, however I require the image and path to scale with the browser.

Comment: romove the `<style>` tags in your css

Comment: @Bart Whoops, done

Comment: you codepen shows nothing ... correct it or put your code here

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, it does show nothing, and that is precisely the problem here. If you remove the attributes I mentioned, the image shows.

Comment: objectBoundingBox units range from 0 to 1 so points="317 343,966 254,964 -6,610 -5" are all massively out of range, even when divided by 100. i.e. 317 becomes 3.

Comment: @RobertLongson That is true, but shouldn't `transform="scale()"` take care of that, as described in http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2017/02/24/scaling-svg-clipping-paths-for-css-use/? I could convert all points to that range, but I have a lot of SVGs and a lot of points - a little tedious. This is just a stripped down example of the project I am working on.

Comment: It does, it divides everything by 100 as I already explained in my previous comment you're still out of range. Get ready for tedious then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was the simple case of adjusting the scale from 0.01 to 0.001!

[Updated working codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/YepbqP)

```
<img id="preview-img" width="100%" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg" style="clip-path: url(&quot;#clipPolygon&quot;);" class="moving">
<svg width="0" height="0" >
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.001)">
    <polygon id="poly1" points="317 543,966 254,964 -6,610 -5">
      <animate id="poly1Anim" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="" fill="freeze" />
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Choosing the right **scale**:

As clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" uses the size of the original path (in absolute pixels) and clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" uses 0 to 1 as the coordinate system, the correct scale is

```
scale(1/x, 1/y)
```

So for a svg with coordinates meant for a 1280x800 px image, the correct scale would be:

```
scale(0.00078125, 0.00125)
```